# Is there a RabbitMQ/pika equivalent to ZMQ's CONFLATE option?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, messaging, pika

I want my pub/sub to store only the last available message on the channel, and dump all prior ones that wouldn't have been consumed because of the consumer being too slow (or paused). ZMQ has the [CONFLATE](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-setsockopt) option, but does RabbitMQ  have a similar option on Python (pika)?

The publisher updates at 50Hz, while some subscribers cannot process quite that fast (between 10 to 50Hz). I don't want them to process the oldest message in queue (which means processing data that is already outdated); it must process only the last available message when it's ready to consume.

Comment: Can you provide more details? RabbitMQ has several options to deal with this, but I don’t know which one to recommend as your question lacks sufficient detail. For example, how slow is “too slow?”

Comment: Publisher updates at 50Hz while some subscribers cannot process more than between 10 to 50Hz. I don't want them to process the oldest message in queue (which means processing data that is already outdated), it must process only the last available message when it's ready to consume. It could be interesting to explain all the options you are thinking to with their benefits and drawbacks for later readers though.

Comment: It sounds like you need a data structure other than a queue, though. A queue is designed to hold more than one thing. A data structure that holds exactly one thing is quite trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ actually does support the scenario as-described out of the box, via the [Maximum Queue Length feature](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html).

From the documentation:

> The maximum length of a queue can be limited to a set number of messages... In all cases the number of ready messages is used; unacknowledged messages do not count towards the limit.
>
> The default behaviour for RabbitMQ when a maximum queue length or size is set and the maximum is reached is to drop or dead-letter messages from the front of the queue (i.e. the oldest messages in the queue).

Comment: That won't work for use cases like price updates.  E.g. when price for product X is update, a message is published.  The price is updated more frequently than consumers process the update messages, only the most recent price should be processed.  I.e. "last one wins" is the desired policy.   The [Deduplication plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) almost gets you there, but it enforces a "first one wins" policy.   Kafka supports this OOTB.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel - such a situation cannot exist in a properly-designed system. The end-consumer simply would drop all incoming messages when it is busy. In any case, that's what the feature does for you, so I don't see the point you're trying to make.

Comment: Google "Last Value Queue".  As I say, this is a well known use case.  Not original to me at all :--)   It is supported by Kafka, ActiveMQ Artemis and others.  But not RabbitMQ, so far as I can tell.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel - it appears that perhaps you didn't read my answer... please see my answer.

Comment: I read it.  And that's fine as a last ditch measure to keep rabbitmq from collapsing under load.  And, I agree, _that_ should not happen in normal operations.  If/whan it does, you should look at your scaling.   My comment  has nothing to  do with that.  I'm saying something else: there are business use cases where "first one wins" de-duplication based on a natural key defined by the app developer.  These aren't related to scaling rabbitmq or protecting the queueing system.  Rather it uses the queueing system to help other elements of the larger system avoid dealing with already stale data.